# how to bind html select option value to pl sql procedure (HTML & PHP)

Tags: php, html, oracle, plsql

I simplified my code as much as possible.

My problem is that the stadium value from the selected option is binded to the procedure wrongly. It always returns 'F'. However, I could not find any solution to that.

```html
$stid = oci_parse($conn,"SELECT Stadium_Name FROM Stadium");
oci_execute($stid);
echo "<select name='stadium'>";
echo "<option value='' ></option>"; 
if ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)) {
    $name = $row['STADIUM_NAME'];
        echo "<option value='" . $name .  "'>" . $name . "</option>";
    while ($row = oci_fetch_array($stid, OCI_ASSOC+OCI_RETURN_NULLS)){
        $name = $row['STADIUM_NAME'];
        echo "<option value='" . $name .  "'>" . $name . "</option>";
    }

}

        $var=$_POST['stadium'];
        $stid = oci_parse($conn, "begin Package.enter_team(:stadium,:result); end;");
        oci_bind_by_name($stid, ":cursbv", $curs, -1, OCI_B_CURSOR);
        oci_bind_by_name($stid,':stadium',$var);
        oci_bind_by_name($stid,':result',$result,8);
        oci_execute($stid);
        oci_execute($curs);
```

MY PL/SQL PROCEDURE:

```
    PROCEDURE enter_team(
    stadium IN VARCHAR2,
    a_RESULT OUT CHAR)
    IS
    BEGIN
            insert into Belongsto values(stadium);
            a_RESULT:='T';
    EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        a_RESULT:='F';
        ROLLBACK;

    END enter_team;
```

Comment: Perhaps you should log the exception instead of swallowing it in the `when others`.

Comment: How can I do that or how do i know what it returns? Also, when I run the procedure from the Oracle SQL Developer it works fine.

Comment: Thank youu :) when I log the exception, i found my mistake. It results from the other part of the code.